# Creating a virtualenv inside a specific directory with virtualenv / virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Is there a way for creating the virtualenv folder in a specific directory (i.e., the current directory) using virtualenv / virtualenvwrapper, instead of the default one (i.e., `WORKON_HOME`).

Something equivalent to:

```sh
$ python -m venv env # this creates the folder `env` in the current path
```

Comment: `virtualenv` — yes: just do `virtualenv env` or `virtualenv /path/to/env`

Comment: `virtualenvwrapper` — no; the entire idea of `virtualenvwrapper` is to manage virtual environments in a central location.

Comment: thanx for pointing out the rationale behind `virtualenvwrapper`

Comment: `virtualenvwrapper` -- yes: you can set `WORKON_HOME` to another directory and create the environment there. You can set it back. It's easy to manage with a few bash aliases.

Answer (score 7):

use `virtualenv /pathto/env` for this.